# Woocommerce get_term() count and get_terms() count different

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using php in woocommerce on a post and would like to show/hide products in a category based upon their stock level.  Currently using get_term() and the product count includes "out-of-stock" products.  Using get_terms() and the product count for that same category counts only "in-stock" products.  How do I write my if else condition statement to use the get_terms count of a specific product category?

Here is the code I have so far ("if" is true when products in this category are "out-of-stock".  Would like "if" to be true only when products in this category are "in-stock"):

```
<?php
$term = get_term(373, 'product_cat' );
$category = $term->name;
$theCount = $term->count;
if ( ( $category = 'Outlet Other' ) && ( $theCount > 0 ) ){
    echo '[product_category category="outlet-other" per_page="100" orderby="menu_order" order="asc"]';} 
else {
    echo 'There are currently no products in this category.  Please check back soon!';}
?>
```

Here is other code I have on the page for testing purposes that shows the product count for this category using get_terms() equal to "in-stock" quantity:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
foreach( $terms as $term ){
    echo 'Product Category: ' . $term->name . ' - Count: ' . $term->count . "\r\n";}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$term = get_term(373, 'product_cat' );
$category = $term->name;
$termsother = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
    foreach( $termsother as $termsnew ) {
        if (($termsnew->count > 0) && ($termsnew->name == $category)) {
          echo '[product_category category="' . $termsnew->slug . '" per_page="100" orderby="menu_order" order="asc"]';
        }
        elseif (($termsnew->count == 0) && ($termsnew->name == $category)) {
          echo 'There are currently no products in this category. Please check back soon!';
        }
        else {
          //echo 'If and ElseIf are false!';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the if statement, use your test code to check if there are products in the category that are in stock and add an additional condition to your if statement. See code below.

```
<?php
$term = get_term(373, 'product_cat' );
$category = $term->name;
$theCount = $term->count;
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
$category_has_in_stock_items = false;
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    if ($term->count > 0) {
        category_has_in_stock_items = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (($category = 'Outlet Other') && ($theCount > 0) && $category_has_in_stock_items){
    echo '[product_category category="outlet-other" per_page="100" orderby="menu_order" order="asc"]';} 
else {
    echo 'There are currently no products in this category.  Please check back soon!';}
?>
```

Comment: hi brulecap, thanks for your response (did notice a missing $ for category_has_in_stock_items...no biggie).  I applied the additional logic with no luck.  Still testing and making minor modifications to the logic and will report back my findings.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Those pesky $'s get me all the time. Hope you found that early on and it didn't cause too much frustration. In looking at my code suggestion a second time, I notice that $term is getting reassigned in the foreach loop. You might consider using a separate variable there...

Comment: Thank you for your help.  $term was getting reassigned in the foreach loop.  I just changed the variable to $termnew and also added a ifelse condition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it refers exactly to the question asked by the questioner, but I had similar problems with `get_terms` in WP REST API. After debugging an hour I found that WooCommerce is changing the terms count only if `is_admin() || is_ajax()`:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/51912c659db971dcc1bf4a9a31a33777904ec627/includes/wc-term-functions.php#L530-L533

Solution: Add a `__return_true` filter before your `get_terms` function call to simulate an AJAX request in WP REST API:

```php
add_filter('wp_doing_ajax', '__return_true');
$terms = get_terms([
    // [...]
    'pad_counts' => 1 // This is necessery if you want to correct parent categories count, too
]);
remove_filter('wp_doing_ajax', '__return_true');
```